# s2member subscription button does not allow bank account as funding source?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I have a membership website with s2member free for wordpress and paypal business account.

The recurring payment button or subscription button doesn't seem to work when a member's paypal account has a bank account as their only funding source. They are asked to add a credit card to their paypal account, which they do not want to do.

I am no expert at how paypal works and find the documentation confusing. I am not sure if this is normal paypal behaviour, or if it is because there is a currency or country issue. The website and business paypal account are based in Spain. The member trying to subscribe is in Germany with  a German paypal account. Both are in euros, but the German bank account could be the problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I seem to be going around in circles over this. I have turned on the option to accept bank transfers and German Giropay in our paypal account, but this does not seem to help. Upgrading accounts would be a problem as this is a charity website and they need to keep costs down.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bank account can only be used for "Instant Transfer" funding if a credit card is available as a backup funding source, for if the transfer fails.